# How exactly does a WSP deploy a dll internally

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, gac, wsp

i am facing a problem with deploying dlls with a WSP. After deploying the first version of the dll using a WSP, if I want to change the dll and redeploy after retracting, it is still referring to the old assembly, even though it is no longer there in GAC. Is there any caching feature in Sharepoint that is not very obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define "it" in the sentence "....after retracting, *it* is still referring to the old assembly..."

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying to the GAC, you need to make sure that IIS or the application pool is getting reset after you make any change.  The DLL definitely gets cached.

Comment: He probably needs an iisreset.

Answer (score 1):

**Deployed code will not reload**. On a similar issue when deploying to the Bin. Although a WSP project may be directed (in the Manifest) to only install and load from the BIN, if an old copy of the given DLL also exist in the GAC - it gets loaded first. Deleting the GAC DLL, and doing an IISReset resolves the issue. Redirecting the load back to the Bin. This can easily occur when using WSPBuilder if you hit the 'Copy to GAC' option. Oops.